# Angular and Typescript: Can't find names - Error: cannot find name

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using Angular (version 2) with TypeScript (version 1.6) and when I compile the code I get these errors:

```
Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
    node_modules/angular2/src/core/change_detection/parser/locals.d.ts(4,42): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
    node_modules/angular2/src/core/facade/collection.d.ts(1,25): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MapConstructor'.
    node_modules/angular2/src/core/facade/collection.d.ts(2,25): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SetConstructor'.
    node_modules/angular2/src/core/facade/collection.d.ts(4,27): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
    node_modules/angular2/src/core/facade/collection.d.ts(4,39): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
    node_modules/angular2/src/core/facade/collection.d.ts(7,9): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
    node_modules/angular2/src/core/facade/collection.d.ts(8,30): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
    node_modules/angular2/src/core/facade/collection.d.ts(11,43): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
    node_modules/angular2/src/core/facade/collection.d.ts(12,27): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
    node_modules/angular2/src/core/facade/collection.d.ts(14,23): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
    node_modules/angular2/src/core/facade/collection.d.ts(15,25): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
    node_modules/angular2/src/core/facade/collection.d.ts(94,41): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
    node_modules/angular2/src/core/facade/collection.d.ts(95,22): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
    node_modules/angular2/src/core/facade/collection.d.ts(96,25): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
    node_modules/angular2/src/core/facade/lang.d.ts(1,22): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'BrowserNodeGlobal'.
    node_modules/angular2/src/core/facade/lang.d.ts(33,59): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
    node_modules/angular2/src/core/facade/promise.d.ts(1,10): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
    node_modules/angular2/src/core/facade/promise.d.ts(3,14): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
    node_modules/angular2/src/core/facade/promise.d.ts(8,32): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
    node_modules/angular2/src/core/facade/promise.d.ts(9,38): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
    node_modules/angular2/src/core/facade/promise.d.ts(10,35): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
    node_modules/angular2/src/core/facade/promise.d.ts(10,93): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
    node_modules/angular2/src/core/facade/promise.d.ts(11,34): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
    node_modules/angular2/src/core/facade/promise.d.ts(12,32): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
    node_modules/angular2/src/core/facade/promise.d.ts(12,149): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
    node_modules/angular2/src/core/facade/promise.d.ts(13,43): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
    node_modules/angular2/src/core/linker/element_injector.d.ts(72,32): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
    node_modules/angular2/src/core/linker/element_injector.d.ts(74,17): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
    node_modules/angular2/src/core/linker/element_injector.d.ts(78,184): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
    node_modules/angular2/src/core/linker/element_injector.d.ts(83,182): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
    node_modules/angular2/src/core/linker/element_injector.d.ts(107,37): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
    node_modules/angular2/src/core/linker/proto_view_factory.d.ts(27,146): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
    node_modules/angular2/src/core/linker/view.d.ts(52,144): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
    node_modules/angular2/src/core/linker/view.d.ts(76,79): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
    node_modules/angular2/src/core/linker/view.d.ts(77,73): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
    node_modules/angular2/src/core/linker/view.d.ts(94,31): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
    node_modules/angular2/src/core/linker/view.d.ts(97,18): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
    node_modules/angular2/src/core/linker/view.d.ts(100,24): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
    node_modules/angular2/src/core/linker/view.d.ts(103,142): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
    node_modules/angular2/src/core/linker/view.d.ts(104,160): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
    node_modules/angular2/src/core/render/api.d.ts(281,74): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
    node_modules/angular2/src/core/zone/ng_zone.d.ts(1,37): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Zone'.
```

This is the code:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import {bootstrap, Component, CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<input type="text" [(ng-model)]="title" /><h1>{{title}}</h1>',
  directives: [ CORE_DIRECTIVES ]
})
class AppComponent {
  title :string;

  constructor() {
    this.title = 'hello angular 2';
  }
}
bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

Comment: looks like there is an issue for that here https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4902

Comment: Try adding the following import `import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';` I'm getting the same issue and for some reason this fixes it for me...?!?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

A known issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4902

Core reason: the `.d.ts` file implicitly included by TypeScript varies with the compile target, so one needs to have more ambient declarations when targeting `es5` even if things are actually present in the runtimes (e.g. chrome). More on [`lib.d.ts`](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/lib.d.ts.html)

Comment: So what is the solution?

Comment: The angular team needs to fix it. Non trivial

Comment: Does that mean we can't use alpha44 or should we target es6 instead of es5 or something else?

Comment: 2.0.0-alpha.45 is good, use typings from node_modules/angular2/bundles/typings/**/*.d.ts

Comment: The last answer is to see the demo : https://github.com/jteplitz602/ng2_web_worker_todo_demo

Comment: "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.3" works, but beta.4 and beta.5 seem to have this issue again, at least when configuring your project like [in the tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html)

Comment: fixed in beta 6 but not sure if its the same cause. 
based on change log of beta 6, you add ///<reference path="node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>

Comment: @Roj I'm still seeing this in beta 6 but it does work when using the reference to browser.d.ts

Comment: beta.3 was transpiling ok, now with beta.6 i am getting these errors too

Comment: Same here, beta3 worked fine, everything else blows up with errors.

Comment: beta 15 - same... :(

Comment: hooray! rc1 joined this.

Comment: I am getting this in Beta 17

Comment: I joined here with 2.1.1. Workaround: "npm i -D @types/es6-promise".

Answer (score 111):

There is a work-around mentioned in the changelog for [2.0.0-beta.6 (2016-02-11)](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta6-2016-02-11) (listed under breaking changes):

> If you use --target=es5, you will need to add a line somewhere in your application (for example, at the top of the .ts file where you call bootstrap):

```
///<reference path="node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>
```

> (Note that if your file is not in the same directory as node_modules, you'll need to add one or more ../ to the start of that path.)

make sure you have the correct reference path, i needed to add **../** to the start to get this working.

Comment: This fixed a lot of errors for me, but I still get errors like `TS2304: Cannot find name 'module'` and `TS2339: Property 'find' does not exist on type 'MyThing[]'.`... Any ideas?

Comment: This worked for me, no errors using angular2 beta.8 version.

Comment: What if you use angular in a package meant for reuse? Any application I try to use a package with a file with this reference complains at tsc build time that it cannot find this reference.

Comment: try to add /// reference for the `angular.d.ts` too

Comment: the missing ../ was what was getting me. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a solution for the new package structure in Angular, I can't find a browser.d.ts in the new @angular/.... structure

Comment: @I.devries Correct, they have removed browser.d.ts. The files are now index.d.ts, and you need one for each angular component, as each is now installed separately in rc.0 and later. You also need to install "typings" -- see answers by Khaled Al-Ansari and theUtherSide above.

Comment: I solved it by adding: ///<reference path="../typings/index.d.ts"/>

Comment: I solved it by adding ///<reference path="../../typings/index.d.ts"/>
 (please note the dots ../../ (you can try with only ../ and if this does work then try adding more (.../) until this works

Comment: This is ridiculous as it assumes you are using typings.

Answer (score 83):

ES6 features like promises aren't defined when targeting ES5. There are other libraries, but core-js is the javascript library that the Angular team uses. It contains polyfills for ES6.

Angular 2 has changed a lot since this question was asked. Type declarations are **much** easier to use in Typescript 2.0.

```
npm install -g typescript
```

For ES6 features in Angular 2, you don't need Typings. Just use typescript 2.0 or higher and install @types/core-js with npm:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/core-js
```

Then, add the **TypeRoots** and **Types** attributes to your tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types" : [
      "core-js"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

This is much easier than using Typings, as explained in other answers. See Microsoft's blog post for more info: [Typescript: The Future of Declaration Files](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/)

Comment: I think the "types" array also belongs into the "compilerOptions" Object. But other than that, thanks alot, I was struggling with this fot the whole day.

Comment: @plexus Thanks! You are right about the compilerOptions. I fixed the answer.

Comment: Thanks for great post, but according to the URL you provided it is not even necessary to augment tsconfig.json, it just really works anyway :) At least it did for me. So the only thing you need to do is to install the required package

Comment: You can even remove `typeRoots` if the only entry you have is `node_modules/@types`.

Comment: Like a charm. As @ilya-chernomordik had mentioned, this also worked for me without the addition of `TypeRoots` and `Types` to tsconfig.json. In my case I also had to update my Gulp gulp-typescript 2.x plugin which was transpiling using and embedded version of TypeScript 1, but once I updated so I was using TypeScript 2 and added the @types/core-js polyfill I was set. Many thanks.

Answer (score 50):

For those following the Angular2 tutorial on `angular.io` just to be explicit, here is an expansion of mvdluit's answer of exactly where to put the code:

Your `main.ts` should look like this:

```
/// <reference path="../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts" />

import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'
// Add all operators to Observable
import 'rxjs/Rx'

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

Note that you leave in the `///` forward slashes, don't remove them.

ref: https://github.com/ericmdantas/angular2-typescript-todo/blob/master/index.ts#L1

Comment: I use VS2015 MVC6 and Angular2 beta.14, If you place the reference line in `_references.js` it won't work. Has to be inside of component like this answer suggests. Additionally, use `../../` instead of `../` for the path.

Comment: @Hani did you find a way around it yet? I'll try upgrade to rc1 and try it out

Comment: So the typings are gone. I guess you'll need to install that separately and when i do, i get a lot of useless packages added as well. Anyhow, even after doing all of that, there is no more `browser.d.ts` under typings folder. Just `.js` files under `dist`. There is a file named `typings.d.ts` so i thought that's the new one, but it didn't solve the issue. Building for 'es6' works, but IE complains. So stuck with 'es5' build and no typings! :/

Comment: @Hani There is a new answer. Perhaps it will work? `npm install -g typings
typings install`

Comment: Downgraded to beta.15 and used the same `.d.ts` from typings package. Also to meet IE9+ requirement, had to build for es3.

Answer (score 49):

I was able to fix this with the following command

```
typings install es6-promise es6-collections --ambient
```

Note that you need `typings` to make the above command work, if you do not have it run the following command to install it

```
npm install -g typings
```

**UPDATE**

typings update doesn't read `--ambient` it became `--global` also for some people you need to install the definitions of the above libraries, just use the following command

```
typings install dt~es6-promise dt~es6-collections --global --save
```

Thanks to **@bgerth** for pointing this out.

Comment: For me it was `typings install dt~es6-promise dt~es6-collections --global --save`

Comment: @bgerth I guess it changed because of the `typings` update, I'll add your solution to the answer

Comment: typings install dt~es6-promise dt~es6-collections --global --save worked for me.  This problem is recurring and intermittent... thx for this fix lets hope it works longer than a day.

Comment: typings install dt~es6-promise dt~es6-collections --global --save worked for me too

Answer (score 32):

When having Typescript >= 2 the "lib" option in tsconfig.json will do the job. No need for Typings. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["es2016", "dom"] //or es6 instead of es2016(es7)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup...adding   "lib": ["es2016", "dom"] to my tsconfig.json file fixed it

Comment: This is correct. Just use caution because some of the types declared therein may _not_ be present.

Comment: @Niels Steenbeek has it correct here. I encountered the same errors doing the exercises for Angular 2 & 4 courses. However, my lib contents where slightly different: "lib" : ["es2015", "es2015.iterable", "dom"]

Answer (score 15):

For `Angular 2.0.0-rc.0` adding `node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts` won't work. First add [typings.json file](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/typings.json) to your solution, with this content:

```
{
    "ambientDependencies": {
        "es6-shim": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/es6-shim/es6-shim.d.ts#7de6c3dd94feaeb21f20054b9f30d5dabc5efabd"
    }
}
```

And then update the `package.json` file to include this `postinstall`:

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "typings install"
},
```

Now run `npm install`

Also now you should ignore `typings` folder in your `tsconfig.json` file as well:

```
 "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "typings/main",
        "typings/main.d.ts"
    ]
```

**Update**

Now AngularJS 2.0 is using `core-js` instead of `es6-shim`. Follow its quick start [typings.json file](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/typings.json) for more info.

Comment: There is an issue with this error in `rc0` https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4902#issuecomment-216495769

Answer (score 14):

you can add the code at the beginning of .ts files.

```
/// <reference path="../typings/index.d.ts" />
```

Comment: This worked for me. No need to install typings globally. Tried on stable angular 2.

Comment: Worked for me too, using Angular 2.0.0 (release)

Answer (score 10):

I was getting this on Angular 2 rc1. Turns out some names changed with typings v1 vs the old 0.x. The `browser.d.ts` files became `index.d.ts`.

After running `typings install` locate your startup file (where you bootstrap) and add:

`/// <reference path="../typings/index.d.ts" />` (or without the `../` if your startup file is in the same folder as the typings folder)

Adding `index.d.ts` to the files list in `tsconfig.json` did not work for some reason.

Also, the `es6-shim` package was not needed.

Answer (score 8):

I was able to fix this by installing the `typings` module.

```
npm install -g typings
typings install
```

(Using ng 2.0.0-rc.1)

Comment: "'typyings.json' is missing. -- (No dependencies)". It returns this error when I run the command in the same folder of the app.ts file. Where am I supposed to find this *typings.json* file, and when should I run the command?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and I solved it using the `lib` option in `tsconfig.json`. As said by [basarat in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33359873/6860493), a `.d.ts` file is implicitly included by TypeScript depending on the compile `target`option but this behaviour can be changed with the `lib` option.

You can specify additional definition files to be included without changing the targeted JS version. For examples this is part of my current `compilerOptions` for Typescript@2.1 and it adds support for `es2015` features without installing anything else:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es5", "dom", "es6", "dom.iterable", "scripthost"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noLib": false,
    "target": "es5",
    "types": ["node"]
}
```

For the complete list of available options check the [official doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

Note also that I added `"types": ["node"]` and installed `npm install @types/node` to support `require('some-module')` in my code.

Answer (score 5):

```
 typings install dt~es6-shim --save --global
```

and add the correct path to index.d.ts

```
///<reference path="../typings/index.d.ts"/>
```

Tried on @angular-2.0.0-rc3

Comment: This solution works perfectly when we need the .d.ts file in a library project.

Answer (score 4):

If `npm install -g typings typings install` still does not help, delete *node_modules* and *typings* folders before executing this command.

Answer (score 4):

This is that think how everyone is trying to do something different. I believe these systems still far from the final version.

In my case, I updated from rc.0 to rc.5 this error appeared.

My fixed was change the tsconfig.json.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6", <-- It was es5
        "module": "system",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "outDir": "../wwwroot/app"
    },
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "exclude": [
        "../node_modules",
        "../typings/main"
    ]
}
```

Comment: This resolved my issues as well. The RC versions are targeting es6 it seems.

Comment: You now are no longer targeting ES5. If anything, change `"lib"`, not `"target"`.

Answer (score 4):

add typing.d.ts in main folder of the application and over there declare the varible which you want to use every time

```
declare var System: any;
declare var require: any;
```

after declaring this in typing.d.ts, error for require will not come in the application..

Answer (score 4):

I am new to Angular but for me the solution was found by simply importing Input. Can't take credit for this one, found it on another board. This is a simple fix if you're having the same problem but if your issues are more complex I'd read the stuff above.

*Mukesh*:

> you have to import input like this at top of child component

```
import { Directive, Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
```

Answer (score 3):

I found [this very helpful doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/typescript-configuration.html#!#typings) at Angular 2's website. It finally let me get things working properly, whereas the other answers here, to install typings, failed me with various errors. (But helped lead me in the right direction.)

Instead of including es6-promise and es6-collections, it includes core-js, which did the trick for me... no conflicts with Angular2's core ts definitions. Additionally the document explained how to set up all this to happen automatically when installing NPM, and how to modify your typings.json file.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this error after merging my dev branch to my current branch. I spent sometime to fix the issue. As you can see in the below image, there is no problem in the codes at all.

[image]

So the only fix worked for me is that **Restarting the VSCode**

Answer (score 2):

Angular 2 RC1 renamed the `node_modules/angular2` directory to `node_modules/angular`.

If you're using a gulpfile to copy files to an output directory you probably still have `node_modules/angular` sitting in there which may be getting picked up by the compiler and confusing the hell out of itself.

So (carefully) wipe out what you have in `node_modules` that is for the beta versions, and also delete any old typings and re-run `typings install`.

Comment: or alternatively... work on other stuff for 4 months and wait for the final release to start over from scratch (which is what I'm doing)

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer doesn't provide a viable fix, and most of the other ones suggest the "triple-slashes" workaround which is not viable anymore, since the `browser.d.ts` has been removed by the Angular2 latest RC's and thus is not available anymore.

I strongly suggest to install the `typings` module as suggested by a couple solutions here, yet it's not necessary to do it manually or globally - there's an effective way to do that for your project only and within VS2015 interface. Here's what you need to do:

- add `typings` in the project's package.json file.
- add a `script` block in the `package.json` file to execute/update `typings` after each NPM action.
- add a `typings.json` file in the project's root folder containing a reference to `core-js` (overall better than `es6-shim` atm).

That's it.

You can also take a look to [this other SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38624888/1233379) and/or read [this post](http://www.ryadel.com/en/visual-studio-2015-fix-typescript-ts2304-compilation-errors/) on my blog for additional details.

Answer (score 2):

Do import the below statement in your JS file.

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

Comment: I'm putting off upgrading a project to latest version, so added `import './rxjs-extensions';` to my `app.component.ts` with the rxjs-extensions file from the angular2 tutorial (including your suggested line) and it seems to have removed those errors.

Comment: Could you please be more specific. Which JS file? the one compiled by Typescript? main?

Answer (score 1):

Good call, @VahidN,  I found I needed

```
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "typings/main",
        "typings/main.d.ts"
    ]
```

In my `tsconfig` too, to stop errors from `es6-shim` itself

Answer (score 1):

This could be because you are missing an import.

Example:

> ERROR in src/app/products/product-list.component.ts:15:15 - error
> TS2304: Cannot find name 'IProduct'.

Make sure you are adding the import at the top of the file:

```
import { IProduct } from './product';
```

...

```
export class ProductListComponent {
    pageTitle: string = 'product list!';
    imageWidth: number = 50;
    imageMargin: number = 2;
    showImage: boolean = false;
    listFilter: string = 'cart';
    products: IProduct[] = ... //cannot find name error
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you must import them manually.

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/retry';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/timeout';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/delay';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';




this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(json), {headers: headers, timeout: 1000})

         .retry(2)

         .timeout(10000, new Error('Time out.'))

         .delay(10)

         .map((res) => res.json())
        .subscribe(
          (data) => resolve(data.json()),
          (err) => reject(err)
        );
```

Answer (score -3):

Update `tsconfig.json`, change

```
"target": "es5"
```

to

```
"target": "es6"
```

Comment: This could cause your JavaScript output to be incompatible with older browsers.