# Angular2 error messages in ASP.NET Visual studio

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angular

I following the quick guide tutorial here: https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

When I run the application, I get plenty of errors:

[image]

Why do I get this error messages?

app.component.ts:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>'
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

main.ts:

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

System.js:

```
<script>
  System.config({
    packages: {
      app: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
  System.import('app/main')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

Comment: Could give some code about what you tried? Thanks! Difficult to help you without this ;-)

Comment: @ThierryTemplier: I have followed the steps exactly like in the quick tutorial provided by the angular team at the link I have added.

Comment: @Bryan I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35660772/2435473) will solve your problem

Comment: @PankajParkar: Where yould I add the ///<reference path="../../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>?

Comment: @Bryan inside `app.component.ts:` at the starting only..

Comment: @PankajParkar: no, that did not work. No I got 66 errors..

Comment: could you add `System.config`(config) part of systemjs?

Comment: I think @Pankaj is right. It's something related to typings (.d.ts)...

Comment: Just tell me all files that you have included before `system.config` and let us know your folder structure.

Comment: Given the confusion in the comments, it looks like this question is missing a [mcve].