# Upgrading typings from 0.x to 1.x. Where is /typings?

Tags: angular, npm, typescript-typings

Writing an Angular 2 app in TypeScript, I'm trying to follow the [5 Min Quickstart guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#create-and-configure).  Recently the npm `typings` package went from 0.x to 1.x.  According to the [official instructions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typings), we are supposed to delete `/typings` when upgrading so that's what I did. After deleting that directory, I ran `npm uninstall typings`, then `npm install typings`.  I now have `typings 1.1.0` installed.

Here is my **typings.json**

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160317120654",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160505161446",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#4.0.0+20160509154515"
  }
}
```

Problem is, I expected the installation to create a new `/typings` and fill it with the [new file structure](https://github.com/typings/typings/blob/master/docs/faq.md#where-do-the-type-definitions-install). However, I still have no `/typings`. Trying to run `typings install` throws the error `'typings' is not a recognized command, program or batch file` (I'm on Windows 7). What gives?

Why it's a problem: The typescript compiler throws a lot of `"Cannot find name 'Promise'" (or 'Set' or 'Map')` errors unless I reference the (now deleted) `///<reference path="../typings/main/ambient/es6-shim/es6-shim.d.ts"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`typings install` would not be recognized (probably because I don't have it installed globally).  To create and fill `/typings`, I needed to execute `npm run typings install`.  This created `/typings/globals` and filled it with the packages in my `typings.json`.

In order to deal with the "Cannot find name 'Promise'" errors, I then changed the reference path I had in my bootstrap file to

the old: `///<reference path="../typings/main/ambient/es6-shim/es6-shim.d.ts"/>`

to the new: `///<reference path="../typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts"/>`

Given that Angular 2 replaced `es6-shim` with `core-js` in `typings.json` recently

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too a while back. To fix it I added
    `///<reference path="../../node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api/typings/browser.d.ts" />` this reference path to `tsd.d.ts` file. The path might be different depending on how your environment is set up. But if I remember right `browser.d.ts` had the references for those typings.

Here is a related issue pre-release candidate.
[Angular 2 can't find Promise,Map,Set and Iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35660498/angular-2-cant-find-promise-map-set-and-iterator/36637886)