# Unable to bootstrap angular 2 app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm working on an app in angular 2/ nodejs and I'm trying to bootstrap the application. I've defined the root component in **app.component.ts**:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'pm-app',
    template:`<div><h1>{{pageTitle}}</h1>
                    <div>My First Component</div>
              <div>` 
})
export /**
 * name
 */

class AppComponent {
    //constructor(parameters) {}
    pageTitle: string = "Acme Product Managment";
}
```

and when the app loads, the page title should be injected into the index.html page in the `<pm-app>` tag:

(index.html)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href= "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel= "stylesheet" />
    <link rel="app/app.component.css" href="styles.css">
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>

     <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src= "node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src= "node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.config({
            packages:{
                app:{
                    format: 'register',
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                }
            }
        });
      System.import('app/main').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
  </head>
  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <pm-app>Loading App</pm-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

For some reason, when the page renders, only the "Loading App" text shows which I think indicates that the bootstrapping process wasn't successful. When I open the dev console, I get the following errors:

```
shims_for_IE.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
es6-shim.min.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
system-polyfills.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
angular2-polyfills.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
system.src.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
Rx.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
angular2.dev.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
systemjs.config.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
localhost/:23 Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined
```

All of these packages should be installed so what could be the problem?

Comment: Could you please try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35660772/2435473)

Comment: @PankajParkar I was actually able to get the typescript to find Promise along with set, map, and map constructor by adding es6-shim.d.ts to the root of my project.