# import 'd3-selection-multi' not working (TypeScript, npm, angular-cli)

Tags: angular, d3.js, typescript, angular-cli

I'm using angular-cli which uses webpack under the hood in a project with TypeScript. Have to upgrade legacy d3 v3 to v4 and I'd like to keep all  uses of `.attr({ ... an object ... })` by changing it to `.attrs()`.

I added `d3-selection-multi` (and @types/...). It compiles without error but when `.attrs()` is called there is an error.

My import:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import 'd3-selection-multi';
```

`d3-selection-multi` just adds some methods to prototypes of objects of standard d3. [Here is the source](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection-multi/blob/master/index.js).

My code (not very important IMO):

```
bars.exit()
  .transition()
  .duration(duration)
  .ease(ease)
  .attrs(removeAttrs) // <--
  .remove();
```

The error:

> bars.exit(...).transition(...).duration(...).ease(...).attrs is not a function

I'm using angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.19-3 'plain vanilla' (without any tweaks).

**What's wrong?**

*Before marking this question as duplicate*: I'm not using System.js and not jspm. The other posts and answers didn't help.

Comment: Did you `npm install @types/d3-selection-multi d3-selection-multi`? Can you then compile `d3.select('svg').attrs({}) `? I doubt.

Comment: Compiling is not the problem. It compiles without error. But at runtime the method `attrs`is not found.

Comment: It looks like the ''d3-selection-multi.js' file is not read at runtime. Some answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38855891/angular-cli-webpack-how-to-add-or-bundle-external-js-files point to 'angular-cli.json' where global script imports can be defined. What exactly comes from there and what from `package.json` I cannot tell. Also angular-cli is a complex beast and Beta.14 now runs on Webpack.