# Angular-CLI: How to refer to .js from node_modules in <script>-Tag?

Tags: node.js, angular-cli

For IE11-compatibility, I read [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html#!#core-es6) that one should add `<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>`
to the index.html.

However, when loading index.html, I always get a 404 for this file.
I have tried many different paths, e.g. `"/scripts/shim.min.js"` and read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38855891/angular-cli-webpack-how-to-add-or-bundle-external-js-files) and [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#global-library-installation) but had no success.

In the angular-cli.json `"scripts":`-array, I added
`"../node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"`
and core-js is defined as a dependency in package.json

Versions used: angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.21, node: 4.2.6

Answer (score 0):

In *1.0.0-beta.18*, there is a file `src/polyfills.ts` which imports a subset of `core-js` content. These imports are said to be performed early on - before the app itself.

Thus, you should experiment with adding the import of your dependency to this file.

Comment: I have problems verifying what actually happens with these import statements. Only way  getting the file present on client side by now is copying the core-js folder into the src-Folder.