# Add custom js scripts to my components in Angular 2

Tags: angular, wow.js

My application consumes an API on a server I have set up.

For my front end, I am using Angular 2.

I would like to use custom js and `jquery` scripts to implement some of the features to make front-end appealing.

The `css` stylesheets are added through the `styleUrls` property in the component decorator.

How do I reference JS files to be able to incorporate libraries like **WOW js** and **Jquery**?

Comment: What kind of Angular 2 app? How's it configured? What's bundling the app?

Comment: The backend and front end are totally decoupled. its running on webpack

Comment: I got it set up using angular-cli if that will be important

Comment: Then have you read e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38855891/angular-cli-webpack-how-to-add-or-bundle-external-js-files?

Answer (score 1):

Install your libraries via `npm install` and add the files you need in angular-cli.json

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#global-library-installation