# Angular load the script only once

Tags: angular

This is my code

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.loadScript('./assets/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js');
   this.loadScript('./assets/js/datatable.js');
   this.loadScript('./assets/js/common.js');
}
```

When page loading each time js has loaded[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6IQP.jpg)

Comment: Why are you doing this explicitly. everything in `assets` folder is automatically served

Comment: first time script is not loading after refresh the window it  load the script so that i have used

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't do the loading of your scripts in the `ngOnInit()`, that way it will happen mulitple times. You can add your scripts do the `.angular-cli.json`file, to do this have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41652742/add-js-scripts-in-angular-2-project) answer.

Or for the current CLI in the `angular.json`, refer to [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts) for more information.

Comment: Or in `angular.json` for the current version of the CLI : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts

Comment: if i add the script in angular json in first time while refreshing the page it has load