# angular2 cli with material lite stepper not working

Tags: angular, angular2-cli

I am trying to add material lite stepper to my angular2 project.

I did `npm install mdl-stepper --save` and then in my index file added:

```
<!-- material lite -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
<!-- MDL stepper -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../node_modules/mdl-stepper/stepper.min.css">
<script defer src="../../node_modules/mdl-stepper.min.js"></script>
```

However in my browser console it gives me 404 error. I tried with `../node_modules` and `/node_modules` or even `../../node_modules` but it did not help. Folder structure looks like following:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Answer here [Angular Cli Webpack, How to add or bundle external js files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38855891/angular-cli-webpack-how-to-add-or-bundle-external-js-files) is useful.

Do not need to add css and js in index.html.

css goes in styles.css and js goes in angular-cli.json -> inside `"scripts":[]`