# How to include jQuery properly in angular cli 1.0.0-rc.0?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular-cli

I use jQuery-based select2 component in my AngularJS project. I had similar issue as guys here: https://github.com/fronteed/icheck/issues/322, and solved it using advice from there. To be accurate, I received error `TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function` when not using that advice.

i.e. I added next lines to configuration of Webpack in `@angular/cli/models/webpack-configs/common.js`.

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery"
    })
]
```

Is it the best possible way to enable jQuery in angular/cli?

I don't think that doing same as in https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-lib is correct way, because

a) webpack bundles jQuery without need to specify it in scripts

b) it still throws `TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function` error when you include it as described in story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve what I needed by exposing Webpack. Use `ng eject` command.

First, install jQuery using `npm install -S jquery` (and I also installed `npm install -S select2`, because I needed that too).

Then, make sure that you made backup of your package.json file, since during `ng eject` Angular CLI will try to add its Webpack dependencies inside your package.json.

After `ng eject` finished working, inside `webpack.config.js` I added

```
// ... Inside require/imports part
const ProvidePlugin = require('webpack/lib/ProvidePlugin');

// ... Inside `plugins` section of Webpack configuration
new ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery"
    })
```

And now select2 adds `$(...).select2` function to global jQuery object properly!

To use jQuery with select2 inside your .ts file, you can add next lines at the beginning of that file:

```
import "select2";
import "jquery";
declare var $: any;

// Somewhere deep within component
// ...

$(this.input.nativeElement)
    .select2(config)
    .on("change select2:select select2:unselect", (e: any) => this.onSelect2ElementChange(e));

// ...
```

Answer (score 29):

i use jQuery in my project as follows.

1. Install jQuery

   ```
   npm install --save jquery
   ```
2. Install jQuery type defination for type checking.

   ```
   npm install --save-dev @types/jquery
   ```
3. Add refenece of jquery file in "scripts" array inside angular-cli.json file.

   ```
   "scripts": [
       "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
    ]
   ```
4. import jquery in any component you want to use.

   ```
   import * as jQuery from 'jquery';
   ```

that's it. the same way you can also use other libraries like `moment.js` , `d3.js` etc.

Comment: The problem is when you use  some library that extends jQuery operator (like select2), you can't use it. You end up with `$(...).select2` throwing error, because `select2` is not known property of $ (or jQuery after your import).

Comment: Have you installed the type definition for select2 library. After installing type definition import select2 in your component.

Comment: Type definitions do nothing with adding select2 property to global jQuery object. I was able to solve my issue using `ng eject`. Thanks for your effort, anyway!

Comment: u don't need to import jQuery, declare var $: any should do

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [expose-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expose-loader). The example below is written for webpack 2,

```
{ test: /[\/]jquery\.js$/,
    use: [
      { loader: 'expose-loader', query: 'jQuery' },
      { loader: 'expose-loader', query: '$' }
    ]
  },
```

Comment: Thanks, although which file would I add the above configuration in?

Comment: It has to be in the list of loaders of webpack.config.

Answer (score 0):

Adding it in the same way as the link you provided will guarantee it's loaded. Otherwise try below in your component.

```
npm install jquery
```

Then use in your component

```
declare var $:any;
var $ = require('jquery');
```