# How do I toggle bootstrap 4 modal using Angular2 Component/ Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript2.0, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am not able to toggle a bootstrap modal using Typescript. I am using the default bootstrap 4 Modal. Here is the code.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And Here is a button that Bootstrap 4 provides to toggle the Modal

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
```

I am not using this button in my application. I want to show Modal through a function in one of my Angular 2 component. I have accessed the html element with the following code.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.modalElement = document.getElementById('myModal');
  }
```

Now I need to activate the modal to show it using a method call. I was not about to find a solution to do that. I tried methods like .show() and other solutions but none worked.

Comment: You need jQuery dependency if you are not using ng-bootstrap. https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/#via-javascript documentation is pretty straight forward on how to open modal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show/hide bootstrap modal from a component?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42735858/how-to-show-hide-bootstrap-modal-from-a-component)

Answer (score 16):

you can use `@ViewChild()` decorator to get the reference of modal in component and then use it with jQuery to call `.modal()` method to open model from within the function.

declare any local variable in your template, for ex `#myModal`.

```
<div #myModal class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
  aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

use it in your component with `@ViewChild()` decorator.

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  ...
})
export class YourComponent {
  @ViewChild('myModal') myModal:ElementRef;

   yourFunction(){
     //open modal using jQuery
     jQuery(this.myModal.nativeElement).modal('show'); 
   }
}
```

you can find steps to include jQuery in your project [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42527105/1160236)

In case if `.modal()` method gives you error saying .modal() is not a function, just declare a `jQuery` variable in your component file as follows.

```
declare var jQuery:any;

@Component({
 ...
})
export class YourComponent{
 ...
}
```

Comment: "In case if .modal() method gives you error saying .modal() is not a function, just declare a jQuery variable in your component file as follows." - not work. Seems like need to install additional jQuery plugins, to make this method available.

Comment: Yes, install jQuery plugins and add them in Angular-cli.json like this


"scripts": [
            "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
            "../node_modules/bxslider/dist/jquery.bxslider.min.js",
            "../node_modules/owl-carousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"
        ],

Answer (score 8):

**3 Step** to toggle(show or hide) bootstrap modal:

1. **Add ViewChild** to access to the modal like below code:

   > Tip: Notice to the **#modal** in code in the first line:

   ```
   <div class="modal fade" #modal>
       <div class="modal-dialog">
           <div class="modal-content">
               <form>
                   <div class="modal-header">
                       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                       <header class="font-12 bold">Modal Header</header>
                   </div>
                   <div class="modal-body">
                       Your Content ...
                   </div>
                   <div class="modal-footer">
                       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">close</button>
                   </div>
               </form>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```
2. **Add Button** for showing modal in your html:

   > Tip: Notice to the **(click)="showModal()"**:

   ```
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="showModal()">Show Modal</button>
   ```
3. Inside your component, put this codes:

   > Tip: Notice to **showModal function** and **accessing jquery sign** inside
   >   component:

   ```
   // jQuery Sign $
   declare let $: any;

   @Component({
       ...
   })
   export class YourComponent {
       @ViewChild('modal') modal:ElementRef;

       showModal(){
           // Show modal with jquery
           $(this.modal.nativeElement).modal('show'); 
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest using a dedicated library that provides seamless Bootstrap 4 integration for Angular 2+. [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io) has excellent modal implementation where opening a modal with content from a component boils down to:

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-modal-component',
  templateUrl: './modal-component.html'
})
export class NgbdModalComponent {
  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

  open() {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(MyContent);
  }
}
```

You can read full documentation here: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal and check a live example with this plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/vAsduJNgB0x6fWPQudQD?p=preview