# angular cli and jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to use the plugin [jquery tooltipster](https://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/) along with Angular CLI 1.5.5 and I'm having some difficulties. Basically, my code is the following:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'jquery-tooltipster/js/jquery.tooltipster.min';

...

$(this.itemRef.nativeElement).tooltipster({
  position: "bottom"
});
```

Then, in the console, I get

> jquery.tooltipster.min.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not
>   defined

I understand that it's because "jquery-tooltipster" is trying to extend "jQuery" (the global one) and does not find it but then, I have no idea how to achieve that. I think that I could use `ng eject` to get the `webpack.config` file and use the `ProvidePlugin`, but I'd like not to eject the configuration and work with the `angular-cli.json` instead.

Is there a way to make a jQuery plugin works with ng-cli or must I eject the configuration?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include jQuery properly in angular cli 1.0.0-rc.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42510334/how-to-include-jquery-properly-in-angular-cli-1-0-0-rc-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do it. You can just includes the  jQuery and plugin js files in your index.html or scripts sections in .angular-cli and then have that line in your code where you use jQuery

```
declare var $ : any;
```

Otherwise, you can try importing the jQuery type

```
npm install @types/jquery --save-dev
```

(you might need to extend the jQuery interface to add your plugin's signature though)

Comment: Ah ! The part I was missing was the inclusion of the js script in the "script" part of "angular-cli.json". So I added "jQuery" and "jQuery-tooltipster" in there, then put  `declare var $ : any;` where I'm using jQuery and it works well. Thanks ;-)

Comment: In my humble opinion, Typescript loses (almost) all of its purpose when we do the `declare var $: any;` thing. If using standalone jQuery, I would certainly go with installing its typings. The problem is: how to declare/import proper typings *for the plugins*?

Comment: You can declare your own interface I guess