# How to use external library on angular-cli? (pdfmake)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, pdfmake

Ok, so, im using angular-cli for my test project and since im new to web development world im trying new thinks. This time I couldn't make it work.

Well, what I tried?

well I kind followed pdfmake readme and into my index.html I placed this two lines inside body tag:

```
<script src='build/pdfmake.min.js'></script>
<script src='build/vfs_fonts.js'></script>
```

well, Im getting this error:

> GET http://localhost:4200/build/pdfmake.min.js 
>   GET http://localhost:4200/build/vfs_fonts.js 404 (Not Found)

So, I took than away, and into my component I only imported pdfmake, like this:

```
import * as pdfmake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake.js';
```

and what it does? well, nothing, i still didn't called it any where in my code, doing now:

pdfmake.createPdf(this.docDefinition).download();

docDefinition stands for my pdf content.

ok, and now? This error appears:

> ERROR Error: File 'Roboto-Regular.ttf' not found in virtual file
>   system

ok, I probably need to import vfs_font, where? well, I have no idea, i tried importing in angular-cli.json at scripts tag, nope, dont work, I even tried importing at my component, nope.

I tried using ng-pdf-make library found ant npm site, well it doesn't work at all.

Im probably making an novice mistake, sorry if its something easy and dumb :P.

@Edit

I tried the same thing he did, and in fact it works with jquery in my project, but it doesn't work for pdfmake.

This is my angular-cli.json script tag:

```
"scripts": [
        "../node_modules/pdfmake/build/pdfmake.min.js",
        "../node_modules/pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js",
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
        "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
      ],
```

and there is the fact that I cant use pdfmake.createPdf("content") even with the vfs_fonts import:

```
import * as pdfmake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake.min.js';
import * as pdfFonts from 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js';
```

Comment: Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38855891/angular-cli-webpack-how-to-add-or-bundle-external-js-files)?

Comment: Where is your `pdfmake.min.js` and other file in your project file structure? If it is typical cli project, you should put them in `dist` folder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular Cli Webpack, How to add or bundle external js files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38855891/angular-cli-webpack-how-to-add-or-bundle-external-js-files)

Comment: @GangadharJannu yeap

Comment: @ShanilFernando  using npm install like i did place the library at nodes_modules/pdfmake... and pdfmake.min.js is located at node_modules/pdfmake/build/pdfmake.min.js

Comment: Also, you load the library dynamicaly more here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73122134/9869753

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need install your pdfmake through npm

```
npm install pdfmake --save
```

it will save your package in `node_modules`

after that you can access `pdfmake`  like this

```
 import * as pdfMake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake';
 import * as pdfFonts from 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts';
```

before using pdfMake initialize like this

```
 pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;
```

**example:-**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 import * as pdfMake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake';
 import * as pdfFonts from 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
constructor(){
     //called first time before the ngOnInit()
     pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;
      var dd = { content: 'your pdf data' };
    pdfMake.createPdf(dd).download();
  }

}
```

its should work.

you don't need add any thing in the index.html or scripts.

Comment: pdfmake.createPdf("your data");

Comment: still getting the same error ._.: Error: File 'Roboto-Regular.ttf' not found in virtual file system

Comment: happy to help if your problem resolved than select my answer.

Comment: How to pass table as content in  var dd = { content: 'your pdf data' };

Answer (score 0):

pdfmake.min.js is in node_modules, so how do the browser access the pdfmake.min.js in node_modules? Only the `dist` folder contents are available for the outside world, thus to the browser.

Install npm module as @Jonnysai said and configure `.angular-cli.json` as follows

```
{
...
"scripts": ["node_modules/pdfmake/build/pdfmake.min.js"],
...
}
```

All other static assets like `Roboto-Regular.ttf` copy into `src/assets/` folder. The whole `assets` folder will be automatically copy into `dist` while transpiling. Then in your index.html, include them like `assets/oboto-Regular.ttf`

Comment: I installed like @Jonnysai said, my scripts in .angualr-cli.json are like yours. About including assets/Roboto-Regular.ttf I need to use style tag or other, im still new to html :P

Comment: Then try it by manually copying in to assets folder and include in the HTML accordingly. But I don't recommend this way. But you can have a try.