# Making pdfMake work with Angular 4 and webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, pdfmake

I want to use `pdfMake` in my `Angular 4` app so I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45014497/how-to-use-external-library-on-angular-cli-pdfmake), but since I'm using `webpack`, `webpack` gave me this error:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake'
```

So, I added the scripts to my `vendor.ts` list

```
import 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake';
import 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts';
```

changed my `ProvidePlugin` to the following:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
        Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
        pdfMake: 'pdfmake'
    }),
```

and did this in the component where I wanna use `pdfMake`

```
//imports
declare var pdfMake: any;
declare var pdfFonts: any;

@Component....
export class MyComponent {
    constructor () {
         pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;
         var dd = { content: 'your pdf dataaaaaaaa' };
         pdfMake.createPdf(dd).download();
    }

}
```

This gave me the `ReferenceError: pdfFonts is not defined` error, but if I comment out the first line in the constructor and the declaration, I get this error:

```
ERROR Error: File 'Roboto-Regular.ttf' not found in virtual file system
```

which is a `pdfMake` error.

My question would be how to declare the fonts from the `vfs_fonts` file so I can use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up making a PrinterService that looks like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class PrinterService {
    private readonly pdfFonts: any;
    pdfMake: any;

    constructor() {
        this.pdfMake = require('pdfmake/build/pdfmake.js');
        this.pdfFonts = require('pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js');
        this.pdfMake.vfs = this.pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;
    }
}
```

I have a function that returns a predefined object with predefined header and footer, page numbers etc. so you don't have to type out the document definition everywhere you need it.

Answer (score 2):

I have tested, this works for me.

1. `npm install pdfmake --save`
2. Inside the component or service: 

   `import * as pdfMake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake';
   import * as pdfFonts from 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts';`
3. inside constructor:

   `constructor() { pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs; }`
4. anywhere you want to use pdfmake:

   `const dd = { content: 'your pdf data' };
   pdfMake.createPdf(dd).open();`

Answer (score 0):

In Vs code the console propose to do this:

> npm i --save-dev @types/pdfmake

This solved my import for the dev build and allow me to ng serve my test version.

You must add this line under your imports:

```
(pdfMake as any).vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;
```

It's right under your import where you want to use pdfMake.

You can't avoid it or else it will generate a blank document not even opened as a PDF document.