# Unable to use @types/pdfmake in Angular project

Tags: angular, typescript, pdfmake

I am trying to use a JS library `pdfmake` in an Angular application. To be able to use it I am referring to https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-javascript-libraries-in-angular-2-apps/ . This makes use of `@types/pdfmake`.

I have installed `@types/pdfmake` as:

```
npm install --save @types/pdfmake
```

I make use of pdfmake in one of the components and it has been imported as follows:

```
import * as pdfMake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake';  
import * as pdfFonts from 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts'; 
(<any>pdfMake).vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;
```

To support the types in pdfmake I am using:

```
import * as _ from 'pdfmake';
```

However in doing this I get the error:

```
This module can only be referenced with ECMAScript imports/exports by turning on the 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' flag and referencing its default export.
```

To resolve this I changed my tsconfig.json as follows:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "allowSyntheticDefaultImports":true,
  "esModuleInterop": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
  
}
```

However the error `This module can only be referenced with ECMAScript imports/exports by turning on the 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' flag and referencing its default export.` persists.

Edit:

I have changed the tsconfig file to the following:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports":true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
  
}
```

But the error still persists.

Comment: Refer import syntax for the default export [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#using_the_default_export)

Answer (score 0):

Add you `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` inside of `compilerOptions` instead
of the outside of it and it should work.

```
`"compilerOptions": { "allowSyntheticDefaultImports":true, }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I made the change and have shown the updated config as the edited part in my question, however the error still persists.

Comment: This should be suffice to solve the error but it doesn't seem to be working for this package specifically.

Answer (score 0):

```
export function normalizeCommonJSImport<T>(
  importPromise: Promise<T>,
): Promise<T> {
  // CommonJS's `module.exports` is wrapped as `default` in ESModule.
  return importPromise.then((m: any) => (m.default || m) as T);
}

// import() returns a Promise
const importPdfMake = normalizeCommonJSImport(import('pdfmake/build/pdfmake.min'));

const importPdfFonts = normalizeCommonJSImport(import('pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts'));


// in service or component
  async generatePDF(): Promise<void> {
    const pdfMake = (await importPdfMake);
    const pdfFonts = (await importPdfFonts);

    pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;
    const docDefinition: TDocumentDefinitions = {
       content: [
         'First paragraph',
         'Another paragraph, this time a little bit longer to make sure, this line will be divided into at least two lines',
       ],
    };
    pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open();
  }
```

also in `tsconfig` should be unable `"module": "ESNext",` or up if you want load library dynamically