# Use Add to Homescreen js within Angular 4 Project

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, angular

I have just started learning Angular development.  I have a task to include below add to homescreen jquery plugin inside one of my pages.

http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen

I am trying to do it as below in my home.component.ts file

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
     $.getScript('addtohomescreen.js');
     addToHomescreen({
             skipFirstVisit: false,
             lifespan: 0,
             maxDisplayCount: 3,
             displayPace : 0
         });
}
```

I am getting below error in my console.

```
./src/app/home/home.component.ts:175:9 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'addToHomescreen'.
```

can anyone help me to implement this correctly in my ts file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

addToHomescreen.js is available as an NPM package. You can find the details of the same [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/add-to-homescreen).
The instructions for using it is also given.

Comment: thanks for your comment. it describes to add the plugin in index.html . I am trying to include it inside a component page.

Comment: I guess instead of adding to `index.html`, you can add the file path to `angular-cli.json` file. There is a `scripts` array in it. Just make sure that the path you are giving for `addToHomescreen.js` file inside `node_modules` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You need mention external scripts in the scripts section of angular-cli.json. More details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38855891/angular-cli-webpack-how-to-add-or-bundle-external-js-files).

Answer (score 0):

let us assume that your addtohomescreen.js is in assets folder.
then try following code:

```
import 'relative path to assets folder/addtohomescreen.js';
...
ngAfterViewInit() {
   addToHomescreen({
         skipFirstVisit: false,
         lifespan: 0,
         maxDisplayCount: 3,
         displayPace : 0
  });
}
```

Hope it helps :)