# Using external javascript in .net core angular application

Tags: javascript, angular, asp.net-core

I am trying to use an external js library in my .net core angular app. I just don't know whats the standard way to reference a js file in an angular component. Where to place its reference and all that. I don't want any floating declarations. Any help.

I see some solutions referring to angular cli file. But there is no such file in solution. Is there a way to generate the file?

Comment: In newer versions of angular, I believe it's called `angular.json`

Comment: It also depends how you created your application. Did you use angular cli or did you create a new .NET Core Web Application using Visual Studio templates?

Comment: I created the project with VS templates..and I cant see angular.json either..

Comment: And how did you configure angular? I would advice you to create your ASP.NET Core project with Visual Studio selecting "Empty" or "Web API", then use angular-cli to create your angular app inside, except if you're referring to angularjs? Please give us more information, otherwise we won't be able to help you.

Comment: I used the basic angular template which scaffolds the first 5 component and views..

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to install your external library using npm/yarn and importing it in the TypeScript file where you need it. For example, if you want to use "lodash":

```
yarn add lodash -S
```

Then in a file where you need the library:

```
import * as lodash from "lodash"
```

However, if you can't import the library in any of your file (maybe because you're just using a plugin of jQuery or something), then you have to define a "scripts" property in your angular.json/angular-cli.json file as explained [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39661714/2261459).

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, the following helps. Instead of using the global variable directly in any service or component, I found it easier to maintain the third party dependency if we could hook into angular bootstrapping. Ex.

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [{
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: ThirdPartyFactory,
    deps: [ThirdPartyService],
    multi: true
  }]
})
export class AppCommonModule {}

export function ThirdPartyFactory(service: ThirdPartyService) {
  return () => service.init();
}
```

Since the factory uses a `promise`, you can code a function inside the `ThirdPartyService` that wraps the third party global variable.

This solution takes a bit of time to implement. But the good side is that it's more manageable and portable to another module or application. The reason I mentioned `APP_INITIALIZER` is that you can do all the above before the app starts. Otherwise, the service `ThirdPartyService` itself will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Webpack, you can define externals:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  externals: {
    jquery: 'jQuery'
  }
};
```

Then, you can import the external when needed:

```
import $ from 'jquery';

$('.my-element').animate(/* ... */);
```

Whatever external library you're using, you need to find out what the global exported symbols is (for example, for jQuery, its just 'jQuery'.