# Typings angular cannot find name error

Tags: node.js, express, angular, typescript-typings

I am getting "Cannot find name 'Promise' errors when trying to run an angular2-express app "npm run develop"

```
node_modules/@angular/common/src/directives/ng_class.d.ts(81,34):error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
[1] node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/lang.d.ts(11,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[1] node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/lang.d.ts(12,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
[1] node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/lang.d.ts(67,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[1] node_modules/@angular/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.d.ts(41,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[1] node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_init.d.ts(16,18): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[1] node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(99,88): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[1] node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(134,67): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[1] node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(150,109): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[1] node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(202,67): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[1] node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(204,109): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[1] node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(236,42): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[1] node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(331,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[1] node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(1,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MapConstructor'.
[1] node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(2,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SetConstructor'.
[1] node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(4,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[1] node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(4,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[1] node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(7,9): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[1] node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(8,30): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[1] node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(11,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[1] node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(12,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[1] node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(14,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[1] node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(15,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[1] node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(100,41): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
[1] node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(101,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
[1] node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(102,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
[1] node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts(11,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[1] node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts(12,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
[1] node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts(67,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[1] node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/compiler.d.ts(47,76): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
[1] node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/compiler.d.ts(62,57): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

.....
.....
```

These are the contents of several files

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "angular2-express-starter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Starter application of Angular2 on Express",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "concurrently \"tsc -w -p ./server\" \"tsc -w -p ./client\" \"nodemon ./server/bin/www\" ",
    "twc:client:w": "tsc -w -p ./client",
    "twc:server:w": "tsc -w -p ./server",
    "typings": "typings install",
    "bundle": "node tools/builder.js",
    "bundle:prod": "node tools/builder.js --prod",
    "postinstall": "typings install && tsc -p ./server"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 5.4.1 < 6"
  },
  "author": "Vlado Tešanović",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^0.8.7",
    "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "express-jwt": "^3.3.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^5.7.0",
    "jwt-simple": "*",
    "morgan": "*",
    "mysql": "^2.11.1",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/forms": "0.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/router": "^3.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "^2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.15",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.1.18",
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ng-semantic": "^1.0.33",
    "nodemon": "^1.9.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "retyped-bcrypt-tsd-ambient": "0.0.0-0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "systemjs-builder": "^0.15.17",
    "yargs": "^4.8.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  }
}
```

**typings.json**

```
{
    "globalDependencies": {
        "body-parser": "registry:dt/body-parser#0.0.0+20160619023215",
        "es6-collections": "registry:dt/es6-collections#0.5.1+20160316155526",
        "es6-promise": "registry:dt/es6-promise#0.0.0+20160614011821",
        "express": "registry:dt/express#4.0.0+20160708185218",
        "express-serve-static-core": "registry:dt/express-serve-static-core#4.0.0+20160715232503",
        "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255",
        "jquery": "registry:dt/jquery#1.10.0+20160704162008",
        "mime": "registry:dt/mime#0.0.0+20160316155526",
        "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160720070758",
        "serve-favicon": "registry:dt/serve-favicon#0.0.0+20160316155526",
        "serve-static": "registry:dt/serve-static#0.0.0+20160606155157"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "jsonwebtoken": "registry:npm/jsonwebtoken#5.5.4+20160208220328"
      }
    }
```

**main.ts**

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule }              from './components/app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**app.ts**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';
import { Header } from './header/header'
import { Footer } from './footer/footer'
import { UserService } from "../services/user.service";

@Component({
    directives: [ ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Header, Footer ],
    selector: "app",
    templateUrl: "client/components/app.html",
    styles: [
        './rajd-theme.css'
    ]
})
export class App {
    constructor(private userService: UserService) {

    }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }       from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule  } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule  } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule  } from '@angular/router';

import { App }   from './app.ts';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [App],
    imports:      [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule
    ],
    bootstrap:    [App],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Note that I am using angular rc5 and NgModules.

Comment: I guess [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35660772/2435473) should help you

Comment: already tried this, didn't work @PankajParkar

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with this, but I managed to fix it by changing `"target": "es2015"` in `tsconfig.json`. I cannot tell you why this fixed the issue for me, but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

IF you are experience cannot find name error., mostly you have changed some files in the base setup or may be you didn't finish the node package installation successfully. Angular2 doesn't use typings package anymore.

solution:

clone the following repository https://github.com/angular/quickstart
run npm install in the project directory and make sure it finish successfully
now copy and config your app project folders into the cloned new folder now this will work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding `"lib": ["es6"]` to your `tsconfig.json` config file. If you're using browser symbols like window and such, you could also try `"lib": ["es6", "dom"]`