# Actual Contant Not Displaying in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I am following [5 Min Quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) in Angular2. When I am starting npm, in browser it's showing only **Loading...**

app.component.ts-

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>'
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
declarations: [ AppComponent ],
bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

main.ts

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser- dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<!-- 1. Load libraries -->
 <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
  System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
</head>
<!-- 3. Display the application -->
<body>
  <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: console error please, though `'@angular/platform-browser-dynamic;` missing `'` quote at the end, should be `'@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';`

Comment: thanx for response, it was typing mistake, still not getting desire output.

Comment: I asked, is there any error in console? or any compile time error in whatever IDE you are using?

Comment: this error is showing on console- error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set',

Comment: you are missing something while setup, please refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39117075/2435473) would help you, Thanks :)

Comment: now I'm getting, Did not detect a `bs-config.json` or `bs-config.js` override file. Using lite-server defaults...