# Angular 2 TypeScript Errors

Tags: angular, typescript, gulp, asp.net-core-1.0

I've followed the quick start on the angular 2 site.  I'm attempting to get my gulpfile setup property to transpile my typescript inside of my Visual Studio aspnetcore project.  I'm using typescript 1.8.10, not the 2.0 beta that has a solution posted for it elsewhere on SO.

I'm getting 70 of these errors when running the "ts2" task:

c:/path/to/my/project/Quickstart/node_modules/@angular/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.d.ts(41,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
c:/path/to/my/project/Quickstart/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/compile_metadata.d.ts(347,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
c:/path/to/my/project/Quickstart/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/compile_metadata.d.ts(348,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
c:/path/to/my/project/Quickstart/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/directive_normalizer.d.ts(19,100): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

My Gulpfile.js:

```
var ts = require("gulp-typescript");
var gulp = require('gulp');
var clean = require("gulp-clean");

// Delete the dist directory
gulp.task("clean", function () {
    return gulp.src(destPath)
        .pipe(clean());
});

gulp.task("scriptsNStyles", () => {
    gulp.src([
            "core-js/client/**",
            "systemjs/dist/system.src.js",
            "reflect-metadata/**",
            "rxjs/**",
            "zone.js/dist/**",
            "@angular/**",
            "jquery/dist/jquery.*js"
    ], {
        cwd: "node_modules/**"
    })
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./wwwroot/lib"));
});

var tsProject = ts.createProject("./tsconfig.json");
gulp.task("ts", function (done) {
    //var tsResult = tsProject.src()
    var paths = {
        scripts: ['./wwwroot/app/*.ts']
    };

    gulp.src(paths.scripts).pipe(gulp.dest('wwwroot/app'));
});

gulp.task('ts2', function (done) {
    var tsResult = gulp.src([
            "wwwroot/app/*.ts"
    ])
        .pipe(ts(tsProject), undefined, ts.reporter.fullReporter());
    return tsResult.js.pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/app'));
});


gulp.task("watch", ["watch.ts"]);

gulp.task("watch.ts", ["ts"], function () {
    return gulp.watch("./wwwroot/app/*.ts", ["ts"]);
});

gulp.task("default", ["scriptsNStyles", "watch"]);
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/index",
    "typings/index.d.ts",
    "wwwroot/lib"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": true
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "asp.net",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "0.6.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.21",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.19",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.3.2",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.13.6",
    "typings": "^1.3.1",
    "gulp-tsc": "^1.2.0"
  }
}
```

Typings.json:

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160602141332",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160621231320"
  }
}
```

[image: typings directory]

Transpilation seems to work, but I don't like the errors.  How do I fix this?

Comment: This is an issue with types not being found. Here is a similar question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35660498/angular-2-cant-find-promise-map-set-and-iterator/38876022#38876022 Looks like you probably need the `core-js` types

Comment: Can you post the code for your typings.json?

Comment: I've run into this issue behind a corporate proxy/filters.  In my case, typings could not be installed due to having to be accessed over SSL.  If you find this is the issue, I can explain how to get around it. Though there are many questions here that address the issue.

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck Updated to including typings.json

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck My devDependencies section references TypeScript 1.8.10

Comment: I have not used 1.8 or the quickstart for a while now, so I might be wrong on this. But I believe if installed correctly there should be a globals directory under typings with the core-js typings in it. Do you see anything like that in your project?

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck Yes, I posted a screenshot of it

Comment: Hmm it all looks right. Unfortunately I do not have much experience with a gulp / visual studio environment so there might be something I am failing to see.

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck I'm going to try the 2.0 upgrade.  Do I need to update anything in my packages.json file?

Comment: Yes.. you will need to install the appropriate @types packages. For example you would have something like this `"@types/core-js": "0.9.30",` in your package.json.

Comment: So `npm install --save-dev @types/core-js` for example. Take a look at this answer for more info. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35660498/angular-2-cant-find-promise-map-set-and-iterator/38876022#38876022

Answer (score 4):

Typings will be deprecated with Typescript 2.0 onwards. An easier solution is to use the npm type definition packages. I know you asked for a 1.8 solution, but my strong suggestion is to remove Typings now!

- Download Typescript 2.0.2 or higher from Microsoft. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593 or install from npm: `npm install -g typescript`
- add the following lines to your package.json file `"@types/core-js": "^0.9.32",` `"@types/jasmine": "^2.2.33",` and `"@types/node": "^6.0.38",` or use the command line: `npm install @types/core-js @types/jasmin @types/node --save-dev`
- In your tsconfig.json file add the following:

**tsconfig.json**

```
"typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types"
 ],
 "types": [
   "core-js",
   "jasmine",
   "node"
 ]
```

The core-js type definitions will get rid of your Promise and Set definition errors.

In typescript 2.0 the type definitions are much easier to use. You go through the same process to pull definitions for lodash, d3, or any other js library you want to use. You can find typings with [Microsoft's TypeSearch website](http://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/). Read more about it on Microsoft's blog: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/

You'll want to update your devDependencies to "typescript": "^2.0.2". or `npm install typescript --save-dev`

To update your gulpfile to use the latest version of typescript change your tsProject line to this:

```
var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json', {
  typescript: require('typescript')
});
```

See [gulp-typescript documentation on Github](https://github.com/ivogabe/gulp-typescript#typescript-version) for more info.

Comment: I'm going to give this a try.  Do I need to make any changes to my devDependencies section of my packages.json file?

Comment: yes. You'll need to update your devDependencies to 2.0.2 and make a small change to your gulpfile.js. I update the answer with more info.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the `tsconfig.json`'s `compilerOptions` `target` property to "es6", since Sets and Promises were only made available in ES6.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
...
}
```