# Angular 2/Typescript 2/ASP.Net Core @angular/core not recognised

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, typescript2.0

I am new to Angular and TypeScript. I am trying to run an angular app inside ASP.Net core project. It was working fine when running on TypeScript 1.8. I need to upgrade to TypeScript 2 since I wanted to use ng2-bootstrap and then the application completely stopped working. It is not recognizing @angular/core in the import statement. I do not have a typings config file. I am not sure I need to.

Any help would be immensely appreciated.

My folder structure looks like this:
[image]

Error:
[image]

Package.json:

[image]
tsconfig.json:

[image]

Regards,
Shilpa

Comment: have you gone through [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35660772/2435473)

Comment: may sound simple but I have to ask, after updating your typescript have you tried just running npm install? you may get an actuall error from npm console.

Comment: I don't have an angular2 folder under node_modules. I guess that is for older beta versions of angular 2? The node_modules/@angular has no folder called typings. The solution doesn't help.

Comment: I develop with asp.net core and angular2.  However, I never use asp.net core in the development process because the angular-cli is so easy to use.  When I am ready to build for production I run "ng build -prod" then use gulp to copy build bundles to a separately configured asp.net project.  You reference the script files in the .cshtml views as you normally would.  All my http calls go to a separate backend via CORS.  This is probably not the answer you are looking for, but the workflow is very stable and you don't have to bother installing ng2 in the .net environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all.

I am still not sure why the angular and other packages are not getting recognized and the red squiggly lines are appearing. The build using Visual Studio is still failing with these errors.

However, I am able the execute the code. I just select the last working build option in VS and since everything I am working on is client code, it is working. I am guessing the squiggly lines are because the systemjs refers to https://unpkg.com. I plan on changing this to local paths and checking. I will update this thread if that gets rid of the red squigglies.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried different way of running angular(2+) with ASP.NET core and found gulp as useless,
And I need systemjs as it helps me for ng2 production support debug in future.
So, I have bulit this angular(2+) and material + AP.NET core(1.1) + systemjs template that you won't find another place on internet.

It works in both Visual Studio and Viusal Studio Code

here you can download template:
https://github.com/Longfld/ASPNETCoreAngular2