# I keep getting errors when using angular-cli - Cannot find Set, Promise, Map

Tags: angular-cli

when I generate an app using the latest angular-cli ,

I keep getting typescript errors:

Error:(46, 34) TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
Error:(16, 18) TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
Error:(24, 15) TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.

how can I fix this?

Comment: is it a clean install? or you have added any extra codes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 can't find Promise,Map,Set and Iterator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35660498/angular-2-cant-find-promise-map-set-and-iterator)