# Does anyone now anything about this Angular2-Webpack error that I'm getting: Duplicate indentifier?

Tags: angular, webpack

I've setup webpack following Anglular(2).io guide, but didn't work, so I've found something online to add but still doesn't work and I'm still getting these errors (hundred of it) (after I run 'npm start'):

```
[default] /Users/username/Desktop/Angular2-app/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:21:13
Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey'

[default] /Users/username/Desktop/Angular2-app/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:1513:4
Duplicate identifier 'export='.
```

The structure of my project is this below:

```
-/dist (empty)
-/nodule_modules
-/src
--/app
---/assets
---/components
---/services
---/shared
---/app.component.css
---/app.component.ts
---/app.module.ts
---/app.routing.ts
--/config
--/typings
--index.html
--main.ts
--polyfills.ts
--vendor
-favicon.ico
-packages.json
-tsconfig.json
-tslint.json
-typings.json
-webapck.config.js
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src"
  },
  "types": [
    "hammerjs",
    "jasmine",
    "node",
    "protractor",
    "selenium-webdriver",
    "source-map",
    "uglify-js",
    "webpack"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false
}
```

webpack.config.json:

```
module.exports = require('./src/config/webpack.dev.js');
```

helpers.js:

```
var path = require('path');
var _root = path.resolve(__dirname, '..');
function root(args) {
    args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
    return path.join.apply(path, [_root].concat(args));
}
exports.root = root;
```

webpack.common.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
        'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
        'app': './src/main.ts'
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js', '.json', '.css', '.scss', '.html']
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader'],
                exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/, /node_modules\/(?!(ng2-.+))/]
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'html'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
                loader: 'file?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap')
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
                loader: 'raw'
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
        }),

        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'src/index.html'
        })
    ]
};
```

webpack.dev.js:

```
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',

    output: {
        path: helpers.root('dist'),
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:4200/',
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
    },

    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css')
    ],

    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        stats: 'minimal'
    }
});
```

polyfills:

```
import 'core-js/es6';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
require('zone.js/dist/zone');

if (process.env.ENV === 'production') {
    // Production
} else {
    // Development
    Error['stackTraceLimit'] = Infinity;
    require('zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone');
}
```

main.ts:

```
// main entry point
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {enableProdMode} from "@angular/core";
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

if ( process.env.ENV === 'production' ){
    enableProdMode()
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically what happening is, you have got typing installed in `typings` folder and same is available there in `@types` folder of `node_modules`. So one file is appearing twice. That's the reason why you're getting an `duplicate identifier error`. `core-js` of `typings` folder get conflicted with `core-js` of `node_modules/typings`.

You should exclude `typings` folder to get rid of this error

```
"exclude": [
  "node_modules",
  "dist",
  "typings"
],
```

Comment: @Donovant the other reason would be, `core-js` might conflicting with `es6-shim` index.ts.. have you checked [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35660772/2435473)

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get what should I do, my target is ES5

Comment: @Donovant that is what I explained in the referred answer.. I don;t want to repeat all here in this answer :(

Comment: I've added **/// <reference path="../node_modules/typings/browser.d.ts"/>** as  you said in that answer, but still doesn't work, actually I don't know if this could be the error, but I don't have any **node_modules/typings**, but **node_module/@types**

Comment: Anywhere in your errors it shows es6-shim.. or what @typings folder has..

Comment: Have you seen my **polyfills.ts** ?
Anyway I can't find any **node_modules/@types/browser.d.ts**

Comment: `@types` should have `core-js` & `es6-shim` folder.. correct?

Comment: "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160725163759",
"node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160831021119",
"jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255"

Comment: Please come in for chat