# WebStorm 2016.3 error: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release

Tags: angular, meteor, typescript, phpstorm, webstorm

Hi updated to latest WebStorm and I'm now getting this error:

```
Error:(52, 14) TS1219:Experimental support for decorators 
is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. 
Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.
```

But in my tsConfig `experimentalDecorators` are set to true:

```
{
  "version": "1.5.0",
  "compilerOptions": {
    //...,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,   // <======== HERE
    //...,
  },
  "files": [
    //...
  ],
  "exclude": [ "node_modules" ]
}
```

Comment: çould you please try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35660772/2435473)?

Comment: your tsconfig.json doesn't include project files

Comment: @anstarovoyt what do you mean by that?

Comment: @Mr.EasyAnswersMcFly see my explanation below

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**WS2016.3** applies config settings to a file only if the file is included in 'files' or 'include' tsconfig.json section. [[More info about tsconfig.json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)]

So the config must include all project files (or if you have several parts of the app you can have several tsconfig.json files). Otherwise typescript service uses default typescript options for the file.

*Preferred solution*

Your **tsconfig.json** should be:

```
{
  "version": "1.5.0",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noLib": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true, 
    "sourceMap": true,
    "listFiles": true,
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },
  "include": [
    "typings/thera/thera.d.ts",
    "typings/browser.d.ts",
    "typings/main.d.ts",
    "typings/meteor.d.ts",
    "typings/meteor_server.d.ts",
    "your_app_directory/**/*" 
  ],
  "exclude": [ "node_modules" ],
  "compileOnSave":false //not required but is suggested for meteor projects
}
```

*Another solution*

You can specify default options in the TypeScript settings (`track changes` option should be unchecked if you don't want auto compilation):

[image: TypeScript Settings]

**Note:** If you don't like the new behaviour you can disable the typescript service integration in "File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | TypeScript" -> "Use TypeScript service".

Comment: Or just restart the IDE

Comment: Still works in 2020. Thank you! I've been looking for this issue everywhere.

Comment: For TS v5 in 2023 "your_app_directory/**/*" is still the way to tell typescript service to start working

Answer (score 8):

Works in WebStorm 2020.1.2 as well. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

1. Open File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Typescript
2. In Options input add `--experimentalDecorators --moduleResolution mode`

[image]

Click the apply button at the bottom right