# WebStorm and experimentalDecorators errors

Tags: typescript, webstorm, tsconfig

The issue solved in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40728785/webstorm-2016-3-error-experimental-support-for-decorators-is-a-feature-that-is) still seems to bite me.
I just made a version bump on my @angular/cli project to @angular/cli 1.0.0, TS 2.2.2 and angular 4.0.2 and now have two tsconfig files: `/src/tsconfig.app.json` extending the main `/tsconfig.json` file, listed below. [I'm skipping the spec config as obviously irrelevant]

Directly after the version bump the `experimentalDecorators` errors and WebStorm's red squiggles started to strike back on me despite several attempts that included:

- putting explicit "include" fragment as mentioned in the quoted post,
- employing WebStorm's TS preferences as in the quoted post,
- messing around with  baseUrl and paths in the "include" part,
- restarting IDE

None of those really worked.

**/tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom",
      "es2017.object"
    ]
  }
}
```

**/src/tsconfig.app.json**

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "module": "es2015",
    "baseUrl": "",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: can't see such issues when using projects created with latest cli (even with your tsconfig.json file). tsconfig.app., btw, is not actually relevant. What files are the errors reported for? What is written to Errors pane? Please provide screnshot

Comment: @lena Thanks for chiming in. Actually the problems went away for no apparent reason. Now I'm not getting these squiggles, regardless of whether Enable TypeScript Compiler is on or off. Instead, I am now getting all karma functions (describe, it, beforeEach) in red. Kind of frustrating.

Comment: try deleting ""types": [
      "node"
    ]" from your tsconfig.json

Comment: @lena Nope, it didn't help (tried all permutations of .spec. and main config)

Comment: strange - I can see no errors related to jasmine when using your config (without ""types": [ "node" ]"). Do you have @types/jasmine in your node_modules?

Comment: Yes, they are in place. Oh well, I guess one day the problem will go away just like that, without an apparent reason.