# Angular2 intelliJ config error.. Cannot find module '@angular/core'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, intellij-idea, config

I am new to Angular2.  I am following the `Tutorial Angular2 by Example`.  This is the first simple tutorial called guess-the-number

I used the code exactly as described in github provided example
https://github.com/chandermani/angular2byexample/tree/master/guessthenumber.

It loads fine in the browser. It is with IntelliJ setup where I'm having issues.

IntelliJ is returning the following error.. as seen in the screenshot.
Cannot find module '@angular/core'

[image]

My properties file is as follows

`systemjs.config.js`

```
System.config({
map : {
    'app': 'app',
    'rxjs': 'https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12',
    '@angular/common': 'https://unpkg.com/@angular/common@2.0.0',
    '@angular/compiler': 'https://unpkg.com/@angular/compiler@2.0.0',
    '@angular/core': 'https://unpkg.com/@angular/core@2.0.0',
    '@angular/platform-browser': 'https://unpkg.com/@angular/platform-browser@2.0.0',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'https://unpkg.com/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.0.0'
},
packages:{
    'app':  { main: 'main.ts',  defaultExtension: 'ts' },
    '@angular/common': { main: 'bundles/common.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    '@angular/compiler': { main: 'bundles/compiler.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    '@angular/core': { main: 'bundles/core.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    '@angular/platform-browser': { main: 'bundles/platform-browser.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': { main: 'bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
},
// DEMO ONLY! REAL CODE SHOULD NOT TRANSPILE IN THE BROWSER
transpiler: 'typescript',
typescriptOptions: {
    emitDecoratorMetadata: true
}
});
```

> My thoughts on a potential solution?

1. currently loads the module from https://unpkg.com/@angular/core@2.0.0 but IntelliJ would prefer it to be loaded from a file on the computer? Should I  host files locally?
2. Intellij does not know about the systemjs.config.js file? Do I need to create a tsconfig.json file? that Intellij can understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors come from TS compiler. And yes, just like Idea itself, it can't find `@angular` modules by CDN references in your system config: it needs modules being available locally in your project (installed via npm - see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html, for example). Configuration like yours will only work when using browser based compilation

Comment: see what system configuration might look like when using local modules: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-tour-of-heroes/blob/master/system-config.ts

Comment: I think this comment points in the right direction however that example has alot of stuff I dont need.

Comment: I explained the errors in Idea; link I provided is just an example, not a ready-to-use solution

Comment: I was able to get it working using the angular of heros from the link you provided..  I also copied over module and templates. Intellij played nicely and it also it gave more upto date angular versions and functions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think you need to create tsconfig.json,

And turn on typescript compiler in IntelliJ Settings

[image]

Also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40728785/webstorm-2016-3-error-experimental-support-for-decorators-is-a-feature-that-is) can help you too

Comment: what would go inside the tsconfig file?