# Errors after updating tsconfig.json and package.json

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-aot

For some context, I just began running through the Ahead-of-time compilation cookbook found here, though I don't believe my errors are directly related to it: https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and updated my Angular 2 project to the newly released 2.4 and everything built just fine. I then, however, changed my tsconfig.json file to add `"lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ]` to my compilerOptions. The file now looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": true
}
```

After this change, I re-built and got the following build error:

> Build: duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey'.

I did some research and decided to remove `"@types/core-js": "^0.9.34"` from my package.json file, which seems to have resolved that error, but I now have several instances of the following new errors:

> Build: Cannot find name 'Set'
>
> Build: Cannot find name 'Promise'
>
> Build: Cannot find name 'Map'

Here is my full package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "docker-build": "docker build -t ng2-quickstart .",
    "docker": "npm run docker-build && docker run -it --rm -p 3000:3000 -p 3001:3001 ng2-quickstart",
    "pree2e": "npm run webdriver:update",
    "e2e": "tsc && concurrently \"http-server -s\" \"protractor protractor.config.js\" --kill-others --success first",
    "lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "test": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "test-once": "tsc && karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings",
    "webdriver:update": "webdriver-manager update"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.1",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^2.4.1",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.4.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.16",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
    "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

To keep updated on new releases, I've pretty much been copying the dependencies portion of the example package.json file here: https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

That link is for the JavaScript version because that is the only one I can find, but I'm actually using TypeScript 2.1.4. Because of that, I probably have some parts of this file that are out of date. I'm just not sure how to determine specifically which parts.

Comment: I am not familiar with Visual Studio setup (intellij user). But maybe try using. `"lib": [ "es6", "dom" ],` Or possibly remove `"lib": [ "es20125", "dom" ],` completely and try using core-js @types. Look at my answer here on how to use core-js. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35660498/angular-2-cant-find-promise-map-set-and-iterator/38876022#38876022

Comment: Isn't there browser compatibility issues with es6?

Comment: Well that is what es6 or core-js does. They are pollyfills for the incompatibilities. So you can use es6 syntax in your code.

Comment: take this for example.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign. Notice at the bottom of the documentation there is a pollyfill example. core-js and es6 are the pollyfills.

Comment: Couple more references. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js

Answer (score 0):

> I am not familiar with Visual Studio setup (intellij user). But maybe
>   try using. "lib": [ "es6", "dom" ], Or possibly remove "lib": [
>   "es20125", "dom" ], completely and try using core-js @types. Look at
>   my answer here on how to use core-js.

**Related Answer:**

[Angular 2 can't find Promise,Map,Set and Iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35660498/angular-2-cant-find-promise-map-set-and-iterator/38876022#38876022)

`Cannot find name 'Promise'` This error leads me to believe you are missing the type definitions for ES6.

**Promise, Map, and Set are es6 specification.**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

You should be using an ES6 pollyfill library.