# TS2304 error: can't find Promise

Tags: angular, lite-server

I am running angular2 using VSCode and suddenly my program is not running and command prompt showing an error
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
I have already installed typings restarted the pc still not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 can't find Promise,Map,Set and Iterator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35660498/angular-2-cant-find-promise-map-set-and-iterator)

Answer (score 0):

Delete you node modules folder and then run the following commands :
npm cache clean
npm install

This should solve your problem.