# Compile error - Cannot find name 'Map' & more - Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, config, tsconfig

I'm having issues with my Angular project. It was developed without Angular CLI and now I'm getting these errors, as it appears it can't find classes inside *collection.d.ts*:

```
Build:Cannot find name 'Map'.
Build:Cannot find name 'MapConstructor'.
```

and so on.
My *tsconfig.json* is the following:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "build/",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "lib": [ "es6","dom" ]
},
"compileOnSave": true]
}
```

I've already searched online for a solution, targeting *es6*, *es5*, or adding other lib attributes. 
Solutions? 
Thanks

Comment: May you provide the entire stack trace please? perhaps the problem is not related to **that** tsconfig specifically. Sounds quite related to this though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35660498/angular-cant-find-promise-map-set-and-iterator

Comment: In my case the map operator was a rxjs operator, and with RxJS 6, I have to import it manually with: import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this combination : 
`"target": "es5",`
`"lib": ["es5", "es6", "es7", "DOM"],`

If that doesn't work try `npm install --save-dev @types/core-js`.

Which Angular and CLI version are you running exactly ?

Comment: Turned out it was a problem with both reactivex and types/core-js