# Angular2 build errors - cannot find types

Tags: angularjs, node.js, typescript, angular

I'm having some problems with Typings. When I run `npm start` I get the following errors:

```
> tsc && concurrently "npm run tscw" "npm run lite"

node_modules/@angular/common/src/directives/ng_class.d.ts(72,35): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/async.d.ts(27,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/async.d.ts(28,45): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/lang.d.ts(4,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/lang.d.ts(5,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/lang.d.ts(70,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/promise.d.ts(2,14): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/promise.d.ts(8,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/promise.d.ts(9,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/promise.d.ts(10,35): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/promise.d.ts(10,93): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/promise.d.ts(11,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/promise.d.ts(11,50): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/promise.d.ts(12,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/promise.d.ts(12,149): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/promise.d.ts(13,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/forms/directives/select_control_value_accessor.d.ts(18,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.d.ts(29,29): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.d.ts(35,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.d.ts(37,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.d.ts(39,44): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(39,88): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(99,42): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(174,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/change_detection/differs/default_keyvalue_differ.d.ts(24,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/change_detection/differs/default_keyvalue_differ.d.ts(26,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_provider.d.ts(105,123): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_provider.d.ts(105,165): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/async.d.ts(27,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/async.d.ts(28,45): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(1,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MapConstructor'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(2,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SetConstructor'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(4,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(4,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(7,9): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(8,30): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(11,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(12,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(14,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(15,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(100,41): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(101,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(102,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts(4,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts(5,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts(70,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(2,14): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(8,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(9,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(10,35): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(10,93): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(11,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(11,50): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(12,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(12,149): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(13,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/component_resolver.d.ts(8,53): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/component_resolver.d.ts(12,44): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/dynamic_component_loader.d.ts(62,148): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/dynamic_component_loader.d.ts(103,144): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/dynamic_component_loader.d.ts(108,139): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/dynamic_component_loader.d.ts(109,135): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/reflection/reflector.d.ts(28,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/reflection/reflector.d.ts(30,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/reflection/reflector.d.ts(32,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/reflection/reflector.d.ts(34,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/reflection/reflector.d.ts(36,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/testability/testability.d.ts(40,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/http/src/headers.d.ts(29,18): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/http/src/headers.d.ts(45,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/http/src/url_search_params.d.ts(11,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/platform_browser_dynamic.d.ts(75,90): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/directives/router_outlet.d.ts(27,54): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/directives/router_outlet.d.ts(33,51): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/directives/router_outlet.d.ts(38,56): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/directives/router_outlet.d.ts(47,65): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/directives/router_outlet.d.ts(58,60): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/facade/async.d.ts(27,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/facade/async.d.ts(28,45): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/facade/lang.d.ts(4,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/facade/lang.d.ts(5,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/facade/lang.d.ts(70,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/facade/promise.d.ts(2,14): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/facade/promise.d.ts(8,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/facade/promise.d.ts(9,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/facade/promise.d.ts(10,35): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/facade/promise.d.ts(10,93): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/facade/promise.d.ts(11,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/facade/promise.d.ts(11,50): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/facade/promise.d.ts(12,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/facade/promise.d.ts(12,149): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/facade/promise.d.ts(13,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/instruction.d.ts(125,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/instruction.d.ts(161,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/instruction.d.ts(179,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/instruction.d.ts(182,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/interfaces.d.ts(21,107): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/interfaces.d.ts(39,104): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/interfaces.d.ts(57,109): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/interfaces.d.ts(80,109): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/interfaces.d.ts(102,114): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/lifecycle/lifecycle_annotations.d.ts(29,100): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/route_config/route_config_impl.d.ts(105,19): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/route_definition.d.ts(20,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/route_definition.d.ts(35,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/route_registry.d.ts(52,66): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/router.d.ts(56,50): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/router.d.ts(68,46): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/router.d.ts(86,45): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/router.d.ts(99,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/router.d.ts(107,64): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/router.d.ts(112,85): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/router.d.ts(114,51): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/router.d.ts(116,72): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/router.d.ts(122,48): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/router.d.ts(128,70): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/router.d.ts(140,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/router.d.ts(144,29): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/router.d.ts(150,19): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/src/router.d.ts(162,70): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(10,66): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(66,60): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(66,70): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts(7,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts(7,69): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts(9,9): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts(10,26): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts(10,36): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
src/classes/animal.ts(42,18): error TS2339: Property 'startsWith' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

Others have had this problem over the past months but none of those fixes have worked for me.

Any ideas? (Angular 2)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38876022/361714

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use --target=es5, you will need to add a line somewhere in your application (for example, at the top of the .ts file where you call bootstrap):

```
<reference path="node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>
```

see this post: [Angular 2 typescript can't find names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33332394/angular-2-typescript-cant-find-names)

I personally switched to ES6 which works perfectly fine so far. I also recommend to do the 5min QuickStart and the tutorial series for Angular2 since you could use it as stable Skeleton for further projects:
https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the similar issue but in Visual studio recently, and I made a lot of google search but could not find any post talking about the issue particularly occurring when running the web app in Visual Studio. It seemed that my app could even be built successfully by npm although it could not in VS. Eventually, I found the reason after a few night work on it. I would like to share my experience here because it looks like there is little post talking out this issue in visual studio. I hope this can help out others who are not really familiar typescript in VS because I found this post easily when I googled for this issue.

Basically, there is typescript tool in VS you can see it and its version in Tools->Extensions and Updates. My project is exactly the one that is created through the tutorial VISUAL STUDIO 2015 QUICKSTART here: https://angular.io/guide/visual-studio-2015.

In fact my VS had typescript extension of 1.8.xx which is different from 2.2 required in the tutorial. I think 1.8.xx is the default typescript vesion coming with VS community 2015. What I did to resolve the issue was just removing the old version and reinstalling typescript 2.2 in VS. The tricky thing that is worth to mention is how to uninstall it because uninstall button was disabled in my VS. Specifically, go to the folder C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\, and search for TypeScript_Dev14.msi in it. Then right click the one of the version number in your VS to uninstall it. After this, you should no longer see typescript in VS extensions. Then, go Extensions and Updates in VS to search typescript 2.2 and install it. Afterwards, my build in VS goes normally. I got the idea here in the comment of Simon Weave. Thank you for saving my life. http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/

What I am still not understanding in the tutorial is it says installing typescript can be done either by nmp -g install that I actually did or by Download and install TypeScript 2.2 for Visual Studio 2015. But it seems the former one does not work though because it does not change the typescript tool in VS.

Answer (score 0):

In your `tsconfig.json` file, all you have to do is change the CompilerOptions target from "es5" to instead read "es6" and that should work.