# Cannot find name 'Map' TypeScript React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this snippet of code below which generates this error: `Cannot find name 'Map'`

```
let scriptMap = new Map();
```

I had a similar error before with this code `Cannot find name 'Promise'`. Solved it by running `npm install --save @types/es6-promise`.

```
let promise = new Promise((resolve: any, reject: any) => {
                    let resolved = false,
```

I find a lot of good answers to solve it with Angular 2 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33332394/angular-2-typescript-cant-find-names) but not otherwise. If I run `npm install --save @types/core-js` I get a lot more errors than the one I have now. I do not wan't to set my target to `es6` in `tsconfig.json` if I don't have to.

Comment: Which version of typescript are you using? Do you have a tsconfig file? If yes, what's the content of that one.

Comment: 2.1 and yes I have.  Solved it myself just now if you see my answer.

Comment: That's exactly where I was going to bring you. Glad you solved it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uninstalled `es6-promise` to avoid duplicates and then added `"lib": [ "es5", "es6", "dom" ]` to `tsconfig.json` solved it.

Comment: That's exactly how you do it :) Maybe to clarify: The used `libs` depend on your `target` configuration. For `ES5`: `DOM,ES5,ScriptHost` are included and for `ES6` it's `DOM,ES6,DOM.Iterable,ScriptHost`.