# Unusual behavior, cannot find name 'Array'

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use the array functionality in angular 7 but I am facing the error saying, `cannot find name 'Array'`. Similarly, I am not able to use the simple array methods like push and pop.

[image: Here is the sample]

Angular7 is not letting me initialize the variable like:

`list: Array<number> = [1, 2, 3];`

What is the root cause and how to resolve it?

**Updated**: tsconfig.js

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Moreover, code is compiling without error.

[image: code compilation successfull]

**Mysterious Resolution**: I manage to resolve the compilation error by updating the visual studio code. The issue was particularly with the visual studio code update.

Comment: This is not connected to Angular but TypeScript. Please add your tsconfig file and answer this question: Does the code compile on Webpack without any error?

Comment: @CanK. please check the updated part. and yes code is compiling successfully

Comment: Can you provide StackBlitz? or Post the related code in the question

Comment: This looks for me more like a VS Code issue. If the build works without any errors... You could narrow it down closer by running tsc from commandline. I am not familiar with VS Code, can you do thinks like reimport the project?

Answer (score 4):

I ran across this issue too! My tsc was compiling fine but the editor was having issues, it was because VS code was using a different version of TS.

Switch to what your config uses via: `>Typescript: Select TypeScript Version`

For reference my editor was TS v3.4.3 and project was v3.5.3

Answer (score 2):

You may be having a problem with your particular Angular setup. Have a look at this issue where others are having similar problems: [Angular and Typescript: Can't find names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33332394/angular-and-typescript-cant-find-names).

See if this helps you: `npm install --save-dev @types/core-js`. It should explicitly install the type definitions.

Hope it helps!

Comment: The Array referencing issue is resolved but the push definition is still missing

Answer (score 1):

I just bumped into the same issue, and after **restarting VS Code** the error message disappeared.

So, as others said, the issue lied strictly on the editor not being able to recognize the tokens properly for some reason I am unaware of.

Answer (score 0):

Update your VS code with the latest version. That might resolve your problem,worked for me!!