# Typescript compile error relating to JSON

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I declared a variable like this in Angular.

```
let user = JSON.parse(atob(t));
```

I got this error.

```
 TS2304: Cannot find name 'JSON'.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can also visit: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28858 please Google first before asking

Comment: is this is public variable or private one for function?

Comment: @PardeepJain public

Comment: @RanielleCanlas i visited those links but i didn't find the solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular and Typescript: Can't find names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33332394/angular-and-typescript-cant-find-names)

Comment: you can't declare public variable with let